# Equality of two limits of r.v.

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

considering a sequence of real-valued r.v. $(X_n)$ convergent to $X$ in probability. Moreover we look at a sqeuence of r.v. $(Y_n)$, where $Y_n\in\operatorname{conv}(X_n,X_{n+1},\dots)$ and we suppose $Y_n\to Y$ $P$-a.s. $\operatorname{conv}$ denotes the convex hull, i.e. $\operatorname{conv}((X_k)_{k\ge n})=\{\sum_{k=n}^\infty \lambda_k X_k| \sum_{k=n}^\infty \lambda_k=1,\forall k\ge n:\lambda_k\ge 0,\lambda_k\not=0 \mbox{ for finitely many } \}$ I want conclude that $X=Y$ a.s. Since $P$-a.s. convergence implies convergence in probability, we have $Y_n\to Y$ in probability. Somehow I need that $Y_n$ converge also to $X$. Why is this true?

Comment: what is conv$(X_n,X_{n+1},...)$?

Comment: @roger: $\mathrm{conv}$ is probably the convex hull.

Comment: Ah ok I see, thanks

Comment: @StefanHansen Indeed. I added this to my question

Comment: @roger $\lambda$ should be deterministic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\Lambda$ denote the set of non-negative sequences $\lambda = ( \lambda_0,\lambda_1, \lambda_2,... )$ such that $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \lambda_k = 1$. I want to show that 
$$ \Phi_n: \lambda \mapsto \sum_{k=0}^\infty \lambda_k X_{n + k} $$
satisfies 
$$ \sup_{\lambda \in \Lambda} \vert \Phi_n(\lambda) - X \vert \overset{\mathbb P}{\longrightarrow} 0.    $$
For all $\epsilon >0$,
$$ \mathbb P \left( \sup_{\lambda \in \Lambda} \vert \Phi_n(\lambda) - X \vert > \epsilon \right) = \mathbb P \left( \sup_{\lambda \in \Lambda} \vert \sum_{k=0}^\infty \lambda_k (X_{n + k} - X) \vert > \epsilon \right) \leq \mathbb P \left( \sup_{k \geq n} \vert X_{ k} - X \vert > \epsilon \right)  $$
which converges to zero by assumption. So 
$$ \sup_{\lambda \in \Lambda} \vert \Phi_n(\lambda) - X \vert \overset{\mathbb P}{\longrightarrow} 0, $$
and since $Y_n = \Phi_n(\lambda_n)$ for some sequence $\lambda_n \in \Lambda$, $Y_n$ converges in probability to $X$.

Comment: very nice! thank you roger!

Comment: you're welcome.